# Netlify option to show directory contents

Tags: netlify, directory-tree

I need to list contents of my site directory on Netlify for debug, but I can not find an option to turn on directory listings. Am I right that there is no such autoindex ability in Netlify as [mod_autoindex](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_autoindex.html) provides for Apache?

**UPDATE**: I tried generating index with `tree -H '.' -L 1 > index.html`, but `tree at Netlify is not installed. Maybe there is an alternative in Python, Ruby or npm repositories?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is an option to download your deployed site for debugging, but there is not a way to list the contents of a deployed directory at this time.

**Steps:**

- Login to https://app.netlify.com
- Select the site you want to see
- Click on `Deploys` from the top menu
- Select the deploy you want to download
- Click on the download icon next to the deployed date shown below:

[image]

Comment: This answer is also the answer Netlify's helpdesk would give you for dbeugging.  If you instead really wanted to create a file listing that you or someone else could see in a browser, you'd have to do it programatically.  Something like a build command of `do_your_build && ls -l your_publish_directory` would show the contents in the build log in your browser in netlify's UI.  To show to someone else you'd have to make and publish a file containing the list:  `do_your_build && cd your_publish_directory && ls -lR > file_listing.txt`

Comment: I had thought about adding the second solution of just listing out the directory, but having a file contents output is so complete I was not sure if I should mention that in the solution. Dumping the listing to a static file is a nice quick and dirty way to get a listing. Also, piece of mind what was actually pushed to the CDN for content is best as a first option. :)

Answer (score 0):

[Netlify added support for viewing files in a deployment in October 2023](https://answers.netlify.com/t/new-feature-browse-files-in-your-deploy-with-the-deploy-file-browser/105196). You access this through the site dashboard, just like the download option mentioned in the other answer.

[image: Netlify deploy file browser]